# .net-core WebApp Dynamic Route to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to migrate an existing asp.net website to dotnet-core (version: 1.0.3), and have some trouble with the routing of the requests. 
The old Structure was: `web.site.com/[categorie]/{id?}`

Now with the new envoirment it should be the same, but i cant get it work.
Since the `[categorie]` field comes out of the Database, and the position in dotnet-core is usualy the controller.
If this would be static i could proberly just define x Routes, but this can be changed on the fly.

So i need a hint or maybe a Solution how to route a dynamic set of `[categorie]` to the same Controller.

Cheers Isparia